# PHP shell_exec does not work for two different app version

Tags: php, c++, shell, console-application

I am experiencing an interesting strange issue with shell_exec...

#### Description

I develop PHP web app that uses C++ backend app for calculations. Server is running on linux and I use shell_exec for C++ program execution. I updated version of my C++ app and since then shell_exec doesn't work, but

- I've checked both versions of C++ app have 777 rights
- Both versions run flawlessly from a console
- Both versions were tested for same data
- Both versions were tested on two different PCs/webservers with same results
- For both versions the webapp PHP frontend is exactly the same
- Second version (that can't be launched) runs faster then previous one

#### Questions

Have you ever experienced a similar problem?

Is it possible that in shell_exec a problem could occur, that during standard execution from console doesn't?

#### Piece of PHP code

```
class LauncherManager extends Nette\Object {

  private $wwwDir;
  private $db;
  private $f;

  public function __construct($wwwDir, \DibiConnection $db) {
    $this->wwwDir = $wwwDir;
    $this->db = $db;
    $this->f = (new Dao\DaoFactory())->setDb($db);
  }

  public function execMeasurement($measurementId) {
    $this->execGenetrac(" -m $measurementId");
  }

  public function execSamples($analysisId) {
    $this->execGenetrac(" -s $analysisId");
  }

  public function execAnalysis($analysisId) {
    $this->execGenetrac(" -a $analysisId");
  }  

  public function execGenetrac($params) {

    // Check path to genetrac can be set
    $path = $this->wwwDir . "/genetrac";
    $this->checkPathExist($path);

    // Check library path 
    $lib = './lib';
    $expl = 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="' . $lib . '"';
    $this->checkPathExist($path . "/" . $lib);

    // Check genetrac executable exist
    $this->checkPathExist($path . "/genetrac");

    // Launch genetrac with parameters
    $this->exec("cd $path; $expl; ./genetrac $params");
  }

  public function exec($command) {
    return shell_exec($command);
  }

  ...
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "shell_exec doesn't work". Do you see any errors in the PHP log?

Comment: PHP error log is empty, shell_exec gives no result. It seems problem is in the backend application, but is hard to determine where, since it works normally from console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shell_exec returns NULL in two situations:

- an error occurs
- executed program returns no output

In order to distinguish these situations use [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) instead:

```
public function exec($command) {
    exec($command, $arrOutputLines, $intReturnStatus);
    return join("", $arrOutputLines);
}
```

You can debug this code by var_dump'ing $arrOutputLines and $intReturnStatus (these are the array of lines that your program printed out and the numeric exit status of your program (0 usually means OK, non-zero means error)).